# Memory access using _m128i address

Tags: sse, simd

I'm working on one project that uses SSE in non-conventional ways. One of the things about it, is that addresses of memory locations are kept duplicated in `__m128i` variable.

My task is to get value from memory using this address and do it as fast as possible. Value that we want to get from memory is also 128 bit long. I know that keeping address in `__m128i` is an abuse of SSE, but it cannot be done other way. Addresses *have to be* duplicated.

My current implementation:

1. Get lower 64 bit of duplicated address using `MOVQ`
2. Having address, use `MOVAPS` to get value from the memory

In assembly it looks like this:

```
MOVQ     %xmm1,  %rax
MOVAPS   (%rax), %xmm2
```

**Question:** can it be done faster? May be some optimizations can be applied if we do this multiple times in a row?

Answer (score 2):

That `movq` / dereference sequence is your best bet if you have addresses stored in xmm registers.

Haswell's gather implementation is slower than manually loading things, so using `VGATHERQPS` (qword indices -> float data) is unlikely to be a win.  Maybe with a future CPU design that has a much faster gather.

But the real question is why would you have addresses in XMM registers in the first place?  Esp. duplicated into both halves of the register.  This just seems like a bad idea that would take extra time to set up, and take extra time to use.  (esp. on AMD hardware, where move between GP and vector registers takes 5 or 10 cycles, vs. 1 for Intel.)  It would be better to load addresses from RAM directly into GP registers.

Comment: I know it's slow, but, as I've mentioned in question, duplication cannot be avoided in my situation. Addresses just have to be duplicated.

Comment: @alexo_o:  I'm curious what the bigger picture is here, and how this could possibly be the best solution to anything.

Comment: It's not the best solution, it's a requirement. This problem is a part of research project in which we are trying to achieve fault tolerance using SSE.

Comment: I think I remember reading somewhere that L1 cache on Intel CPUs didn't have ECC.  (But that L2 and L3 did).  Is that true?  Good luck with your research project, thanks for satisfying my curiosity about why you'd ever want to do this. :P  So do you store pointers duplicated, and load them with a 128b load?  Then compare between the two halves of the register?  I think it would be more efficient to load to a GP reg, then `test 8+my_pointer, %rdi / jne  error_detected`.  Shuffling data around to verify the two halves of one register are the same is prob. slower.

Comment: Well, we do it a bit different, faster way. But it's already details of implementation. I guess, it will be too much for a stackoverflow comment :)